# How do I start a new line in this JavaScript .text line?

Tags: javascript

So I'm new to javascript and I'm exploring it by developing a simple clock on a FitBit. 
Here's my code:

```
if (hours < 12){
    myLabel.text = `${hours}:${mins}:${secs}:${"AM"}:${"\n"}:${"Sunday"}`;
  }
```

I want it to print the following:

```
Hours, Minutes, Seconds
Sunday
```

However, it's printing everything on the same line:

```
Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Sunday
```

I've tried \n but that didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: You're using a template literal.  Just put an actual new line in the code.  Or if you are displaying this as html you will want to throw a `<br>` in there instead.

Comment: @Taplar — They said `\n` didn't work, and that the target is a FitBit (which I assume isn't HTML).

Comment: I'm not referring to a logical `\n`.  I'm referring to an actual new line in the code, as the provided answer demonstrates.  Template literals allow new lines in the value without escaping, where normal strings require escaping.

Comment: @Taplar — Template literals also allow new lines with `\n` and if that didn't work then I don't see any reason a literal one would.

Comment: Which is why I said if the new line didn't work, that you may have to use a `<br>`.  If a new line doesn't work, then the rendering is ignoring whitespace is cases.  HTML is well known to ignore some whitespace, which is why the first attempt would be to try to style it with a new line, or use a tag that forces a break, such as the <br>

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `` `${"\n"}` `` is equivelent to `` `\n` ``. Likewise `AM` and `Sunday` unless you make them dynamic in the future.

Secondly, `\n` should be used to line break JS strings, not HTML text.

E.g.,

```
let str = 'line 1 \n line 2`; // this is fine

element.textContent = 'line 1 \n line2'; // this is bad

<element>line 1 \n line 2</element> // (HTML) this is bad
```

The reason is because most (see HTML `pre` and CSS `white-space` for exceptions) HTML elemnts will be rendered with disregard to superflous white space and new lines.

Instead, you should use seperate elements if you want to explicitly present a new line in HTML. E.g.

```
<p>line 1</p>
<p>line 2</p>
```

In your case,

```js
let hours = 3,
  mins = 5,
  secs = 7;

if (hours < 12) {
  document.querySelector('#line1').textContent = `${hours}:${mins}:${secs}:AM`;
  document.querySelector('#line2').textContent = 'Sunday';
}
```

```html
<label>
  <div id="line1"></div>
  <div id="line2"></div>
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a  element for multiline. Then from JavaScript, you use `\n` for a line break, or just an actual line break in the SVG.

**Ref:** https://twitter.com/fitbitdev/status/930945957151178752?lang=en

[image]

**Sol:**
https://dev.fitbit.com/build/guides/user-interface/svg/

Comment: https://jsbin.com/bodiyelamu/1/edit?js,console — `\n` and literal line breaks are equivalent in a template literal.

Comment: I tried that but instead of a new line, it put a weird symbol (a box with a question mark in it) instead of starting a new line. I can give you a screenshot if needed.

Comment: @xdeepakv for convenience, could you share the reference you found that said that fitbit used html?

Comment: This is just bad. If you want to create a `br` element, there's a function for that (`document.createElement('br')`). Don't use HTML strings in JS.

Comment: @junvar Can you elaborate on why it is bad, vs your opinion that it is bad?

Comment: @Taplar, search for `innerhtml bad` (the same argument as to why HTML strings in JS are bad). Not only is there a **lot** of discussions on the topic already, but you'll notice most are ~5-10 years old. I.e., it's been bad for a long time; it was bad even before more elegant patterns arose.

Comment: I agree that there are down sides to using `innerHTML +=`, as well as some of the other points made, but I completely disagree that using html in template literals is an absolute bad thing.  And my main point with my last comment was that if you are going to make a statement that something is bad, you need to be able to explain why it is bad.  You can't expect everyone to take your word at face value.